# An 500 error comes out when I configure Gitlab for jira application

Tags: gitlab, jira

I have a self-host gitlab server and now I want to connect it with the jira but it returns me a 500 error.

[image]

Updated:
And I try to create a new Application for jira and it pop me an window
[image]

But when I click authorize, the 500 error comes out again

Comment: Where is your Jira hosted? Jira cloud or on prem?

Comment: jira cloud and I try to find the error message in logs but can't

Comment: And actually, it works for a month but crashed today